# How to change default Error message of IdentityServer4 with Password Grant flow

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

When using IdentityServer4 with Resource owner password flow and asp.net Identity, it always returns same error message when login is failed. It doesnt matter if password is invalid or the user has been locked out.

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "invalid_username_or_password"
}
```

here is the configuration of Identity and Identity server:

```
services.AddIdentityCore<User>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDBContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddUserManager<UserManager<User>>()
    .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();

var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
    .AddAspNetIdentity<User>();
```

As I'm using Resource owner password flow with asp.net identity , there is no custom user service for login users in. So how can I show error messages according to what happened in login process?

Comment: The ASP.NET Core Identity integration registers a custom implementation of [`IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator`](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resource_owner.html), which appears to control the response that gets sent back. You might need to provide your own implementation in order to change the `error_description` property you've mentioned. Note that it wouldn't be wise to change the `error` property as this is from the spec. You could argue that giving away more information about lockout, etc, is a bad idea too but that's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I could able to override validation method of that implementation of the IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator interface and return the message I need. Thanks a lot. please answer the question so I can mark your answer as accepted

Comment: It's no problem - I'm glad I could help. I suggest you answer the question yourself with your final solution as that'll be a much better answer than I can provide. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how this worked for me:

```
using IdentityServer4.Models;
using IdentityServer4.Validation;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

public class CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator : IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator
{
    private readonly CustomUserRepository _repository;

    public CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator(CustomUserRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    // https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/resource_owner.html
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
    {
        var user = await _repository.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            var passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher();
            var result = passwordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user.User.Password, context.Password);
            // https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/grant_validation_result.html#refgrantvalidationresult
            if (result)
            {
                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(subject: user.Id, authenticationMethod: "password");
            }
            else
            {
                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant, "invalid password");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant, "invalid user");
        }
    }
}
```

this is registered like so at Startup.cs time:

```
        var builder = services
            .AddIdentityServer()
            .AddSigningCredential(certificate)
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Resources.Get())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Get(baseUri))
            .AddValidationKey(certificate)
            .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
            .AddResourceOwnerValidator<CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
```

For me, to get this to work I needed to *not* include `.AddAspNetIdentity<User>();` at the end of the registration step.